# win32com read first mails of the day multiple times although they are read

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

We are using win32com in python to go through inbox and read mails having certain conditions in their subject and of course it should be unread. After the operations we set mail.Unread = False. We call that script everyday from  a .bat file. However, everyday when we start it the first time it stucks at the mails that are already in the inbox, and read them multiple times until I restart the .bat file. I observe that the mails that its reading are already read, so it should not be reading them. After restart, there is clearly no problem. The mails coming after we start the .bat file are read only once, turned into mail.Unread = False, and the script continues to run. What can be the reason that the script stuck with the mail that are already in the inbox? Below, there is a part of the script

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
    
        self.outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        self.mailbox=self.outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Items 
        

    def runBot(self): 
        """
        Loops over mailbox and if it hits a  message that fits, it calls required methods.
        """
    
        for mail in self.mailbox:
            if (mail.Unread==True) and (certain conditions):
                ....
            """
            The mail.Unread = False is called in another class that uses the "mail" object directly
            """

myclass = MyClass()
    
while True:
    myclass.runBot()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Again the problem occurs only in the first run, after restart there is no problem with the newcoming mails. It runs perfectly. Any idea to solve it helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: It sounds like the `mail.Unread = False` isn't changing the actual message in the  `mailbox`.

Comment: In the rest of the day there is no problem. Newcoming mails are set as unread.

Comment: Then something about restarting the script causes the `unRead` flag in messages in the `mailbox` itself to get updated. Each object put in `mail` in the `for`-loop is probably just a copy of what's the `mailbox`, so setting its flag doesn't actually change the corresponding message in the `mailbox` itself. I may not have all the details exactly right, but something along these lines is likely the problem.

Comment: Firstly, never loop through all items in a folder - it is a performance killer. Use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict. Secondly, verify in Outlook that the message are indeed marked as read in Outlook explorer after your code runs.

Comment: Yes, the mails are marked as read after the code runs, however they are read again.